# Background in a layout not appearing unless I put something in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I'm trying to draw a box around two TextView objects in Android.  Prior to this I had the two TextViews in a LinearLayout, but I'm working on flattening my view hierarchy to improve performance.  When they were in the LinearLayout, the background showed up as desired, but when I create an empty layout with the same dimensions, I don't see the background show up at all.
My guess is this is because there isn't anything in the FrameLayout (I also tried an empty LinearLayout).  I also tried setting this value at run-time, but same result.

This works fine in the layout editor in Eclipse, but when running on my tablet, the background just isn't there.

Any suggestions to accomplish the same thing or any suggestions for what I'm missing would help.  Here's the shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#508E8F8E" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#8E8F8E" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

And here's the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_around_text"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gray"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="first_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/first_text"
    android:text="second_text" />
```

Comment: do you see that in the emu too? if so use hierarchyviewer to find out whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the shape must have real dimensions defined somewhere.  I can make it show up if I define a size in the shape itself or if I use numbered dimensions in the layout.  It would never show up if I used the 'wrap_content' or 'match_parent' options.